# Run a python subprocess to grep for multiple items in a list and append output to csv file

Tags: python, for-loop, subprocess, output, export-to-csv

I have a python subprocess that greps for characters in a file and outputs the results to a csv file.  I would like to perform the same grep in my subprocess for each item in a list and then output the results to the csv file, appending the results to the prior results.  I have the following code:

```
list = ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'MNOP', 'QRST']

    with open('output.csv','w') as out:
          out.writelines(
                        for x in list:
                            cat = subprocess.Popen(['cat', 'LogFile_20130410.msg.log'],
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
                            grep = subprocess.Popen(['grep', x],
                                    stdin=cat.stdout,
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
                            awk = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '{print $14,$10,$5,$7}'],
                                    stdin=grep.stdout,
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
                            sort = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-t ', '-k4', '-n', '-r'],
                                    stdin=awk.stdout,
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
                            head = subprocess.Popen(['head', '-10'],
                                    stdin=sort.stdout,
                                    stdout=open('output.csv', 'w'),)
                        )
```

I THINK my subprocess is working, but my output file only contains the last item in my list.  I think I'm overwriting my data.  Is this my issue or is my for statement wrong?  If my for statement is correct, how do I write to the output.csv file without overwriting?  Also is there a way to write my output to separate columns?

My output looks like this:

QRST 39h0gcro Ack 83ms

Each of these fields should be in a separate column.

Comment: It's extremely ugly and very non-efficient - mixing Linux commands and Python for this purpose.
Besides, naming a variable with a language keyword...

Comment: Why would you `Popen(['cat', logfile])` and pass `cat.stdout` to the next process, instead of just opening the file in Python and passing the file object?

Comment: Why not do this task solely using python or linux?

Comment: "Linux commands" isn't a very good description, considering that they're also Mac OS X commands, Cygwin commands, Solaris commands, etc. But the sentiment is right: if all you want is to run a pipeline of POSIX commands, the bash (or plain sh) shell is much better for that than Python.

Comment: @abarnert Not that it's important, but they are either Unix or Linux flavors. While Linux itself is a variant of Unix. Lately I'm more used to Linux

Comment: @abarnert I know I can do this using Unix shell commands, but I need this to run daily as a script.  I've transformed my working shell command into a subprocess, but need more insight.

Comment: @volcano: OS X, Solaris, etc. are not linux flavors. Calling them "linux" isn't just inaccurate, it's misleading, because people who know what they're talking about will assume you do too, and therefore that you specifically mean something—e.g., GNU instead of BSD (or SysV) userland—when you don't.

Comment: @user2234571: You can run a bash script daily just as easily as you can run a Python script daily.

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem with your code is this:

```
head = subprocess.Popen(['head', '-10'],
                        stdin=sort.stdout,
                        stdout=open('output.csv', 'w'),)
```

You do this each time through the loop. Therefore, each time through the loop, you're opening `output.csv` in `'w'` mode again, which erases whatever was there and replaces it with the new output.

On top of that, you're never closing the file. You might get lucky, and the garbage collection will automatically close the file each time before opening it the next time. But that isn't guaranteed to happen. If it doesn't, you may not have flushed anything to disk from one loop before you start the next loop.

Also, you've already got the same file open the whole time, in the `with` loop. And you're also trying to do `out.writelines(…)` around the whole loop. That will raise a `SyntaxError`, because you can't use a block statement as a function parameter… but if you replaced it with something that *did* work, it would just mean you've got two file descriptors fighting over writing to and flushing the same file.

You could solve all of these problems at once by (a) only opening the file once, in the `with` outside the loop, (b) not trying to call `out.writelines()` around the loop, and (c) passing `out` as the `stdout` for the last command in the pipeline, instead of reopening the same file.

Alternatively, you could *not* open the file outside the loop, open it in `a` or `r+` mode instead of `w` mode each time through the loop, and make sure to close it before the end of the loop. But that's more complicated for no clear benefit.

---

At any rate, this is a bizarre design. Besides the fact that the `cat` is useless, if you really just want to pipe a bunch of POSIX commands together, just use `sh` instead of `python`:

```
grep $x < LogFile_20130410.msg.log | 
    awk '{print $14,$10,$5,$7}' | 
    sort -t' ' -k4 -n -r |
    head -10  >> output.csv
```

That's a whole lot simpler.

---

Or, if you want to do it in Python, why not use Python instead of POSIX commands?

```
with open('LogFile_20130410.msg.log') as f:
    grepped = [line for line in f if line.startswith(x)]
columns = [row.split() for row in grepped]
columns4 = [(row[13], row[9], row[4], row[6]) for row in columns]
columns4.sort(key=lambda row: int(row[3]), reverse=True)
top10 = columns4[:10]
with open('output.csv', 'a') as outf:
    csv.writer(outf).writerows(top10)
```

This isn't identical, but most the differences shouldn't matter. For example, I've simplified the code to not use a regex, since according to your sample data you clearly don't need it.

But it's still not going to work for your sample data—for the same reasons your `awk`-based code doesn't work, just in different ways.

First, `awk` treats `$14` as "the 14th column, or empty if there aren't that many", while Python treats `row[13]` as "the 14th column, or raise an exception if there aren't that many". Given that your input data has only 4 columns, and none of the columns you're looking for are in the first 5, your `awk`-based code will print out 10 rows of 4 empty columns, while this Python code will raise an exception. If you really want `awk`-style behavior here:

```
def getcol(a, col):
    try:
        return a[col]
    except IndexError:
        return ''
columns4 = [(getcol(row, 13), getcol(row, 9), getcol(row, 4), getcol(row, 6)) for row in columns]
```

Or, since that line is getting a bit unwieldy, add another function:

```
def getcols(a, *cols):
    return [getcol(a, col) for col in cols]
columns4 = [getcols(row, 13, 9, 4, 6) for row in columns]
```

Then, `sort -n` handles an empty column as 0, but in Python, `int('')` is an exception. So, again, create a wrapper:

```
def intify(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```

… and use it:

```
columns4.sort(key=lambda row: intify(row[3]), reverse=True)
```

And now, the Python code will successfully print out 10 rows of empty columns too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I'm a beginner at Python, so I'm not familiar with all the commands.  I tried using your last suggestion, but I'm not sure I follow.  Should I be using your with statement within my for loop and using my list?

Comment: Yes, you put this inside the `for x in list:` (and get rid of the stuff outside that loop).

Comment: @abarnertOkay, I'm getting the following error message now:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./latency3", line 25, in <module>
    columns4 = [(row[14], row[10], row[5], row[7]) for row in columns]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @user2234571: Oops, awk is 1-based, isn't it… Sorry about that. OK, change those numbers to 13, 9, 4, and 6 and see if it works. But meanwhile, if you want to do this in Python, you should learn how to debug it in Python. If you get an error like this, try printing out the output. If there's too much to look at, try writing an explicit loop that goes through the rows one by one and tries the expression on them, to see which one is failing, and just print that out.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, but still getting IndexError: list index out of range.  Here is what I have:  ``collection = ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'MNOP', 'QRST']

for x in collection:
   with open('LogFile_20130411.msg.log') as f:
    log = f.read()
grepped = re.findall(x, log)
columns = [row.split() for row in grepped]
columns4 = [(row[13], row[9], row[4], row[6]) for row in columns]
columns4.sort(key=lambda row: int(row[3]), reverse=True)
top10 = columns4[:10]
with open('output.csv', 'a') as outf:
    csv.writer(outf).writerows(top10)``

Comment: @user2234571: Instead of trying to paste code into comments (where it's hard to read, and impossible to see indentation), put the code somewhere like http://pastebin.com and paste a link here. Also, paste either your log file, or (better) a stripped-down version that's got just enough to demonstrate the problem. (And also pastebin the full traceback if it's not the same as last time.)

Comment: @user2234571: Meanwhile… looking at the sample data from your question, if you've only got 4 columns, and you're asking for column 14, that's `''` in `awk`, but an exception in Python. I've updated the answer to handle that. Although at this point, I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, because you're just going to get a bunch of commas with nothing between them…